# Add a label to an abline in boxplot

Tags: r, boxplot

I am trying to add a label to an *abline* in a boxplot.  I know I have to use the *text()* function but no matter what I try nothing appears on my plot.

My plot code is as follows:

```
# Technical Ability SUS Score box plot
par(mar=c(4, 4, 2, 1))
boxplot(
  tech3suscuq$SUS,
  tech4suscuq$SUS,
  tech5suscuq$SUS,
  names=c(3,4,5),
  xlab="Technical Ability",
  ylab="Score",
  main="SUS Scores by Technical Ability",
  col=c("green", "orange", "purple"),
  cex.main="0.8",
  cex.lab="0.8",
  cex.axis="0.8",
  yaxt="n"
)
axis(2, cex.axis="0.8", at=seq(50,100, 5))
abline(h=68, lwd=2, lty="solid", col="red")
text(4.5, 68.4, "Benchmark")
```

But when I run it I get this:

[image]

So my question is, why is my "Benchmark" text not appearing above the red line, and how can I make it appear?

Comment: Because you assume a x-coordinate of  `4.5` but your coordinate system probably is not in this range. Note, that you use `names=c(3,4,5)`. Those are not coordinates of your plot. Use `par("usr")` to find out the limits of your coordinate system or alternatively locate a position in your plot with `locator()` interactively.

Comment: Try `text(1.5, 68.4, "Benchmark")`. Because your 3-5 numbers are labels and not x coordinates. You can check it with `locator(1)` and click in the graph where you want to have your label

Comment: @Julian_Hn, your suggestion worked.  Thank you!

Comment: @Julian_Hn   Could you please add you solution. Right now it looks like there is no answer even though your suggestion work for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments by [@Julian_Hn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55417599/adding-a-label-to-an-abline-in-r#comment97554995_55417599), the x-axis do not match with 4.5. Because we have 3 values, the equivalent correct position would be 2.5, i.e.: the between the 2nd and 3rd boxplot.

Try this example:

```
boxplot(mpg ~ cyl, mtcars)
abline(h = 15, col = "red")

#adding a vertical line to illustrate where the 2.5 is on x-axis
abline(v = 2.5, col = "grey", lty = "dashed")

# using adjust to move the text above the line
text(2.5, 15, "Benchmark", adj = c(0.5, -0.5))
```

[image]